# change in vertical space of top element in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a view controller in navigation stack ... whenever after loading the view controller a change happens in vertical space of top element.

I don't understand why it happens ..

I have set top 5 for the top element of the view controller to the superview

I couldn't fix the problem no matter what ... status bar , top bar ,bottom bar,size are inferred

Info.plist I have set viewcontrollerbasedstatusbarappearance as no and I am setting the status bar as light content in app delegate once..

The problem that menioned not happens with all the view controller only with some viewcontroller it happesn

Thanks for any help

Comment: Add screenshot of constraint.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what problem you are facing?

Comment: Basically its just a vertical constraint ...  lets when the viewcontroller loads the element is more close to upper border of view but in a fraction of second its comes down bit far from top .. I don't know why the movement happens... actually it comes down to right position ... But my question is why it was close the top border and how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you gave constraint like that,

[image]

So, change it as per below,

[image]

I hope it will work.

Comment: If you got the solution then please accept an answer.

Comment: Please check my another answer

Answer (score 1):

First, click on viewController in storyboard.

So, you will see at a right side corner is like this.

[image]

After that, Untick Under Top bars checkbox like that,

[image]

I hope this will work.